# Help down mixing stereo into two separate mono channels

Tags: audio, alsa, shairplay

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W configured as an AirPlay audio playback device for personal use. I am using the Adafruit Speaker Bonnet (https://www.adafruit.com/product/3346) which interfaces to the Pi over I2S.  On the software side, I have installed the "Shairport Sync" package (https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync).  Everything is working great for normal stereo output, but I am trying to power a pair of mono speakers and want to combine the stereo output such that each physical output channel (L and R) contain a downmixed version of the stereo audio stream.

The idea is to have two separate outdoor speakers in different locations, with a mixed (L+R) audio stream emitting from each.

I have the following ALSA config file:

```
pcm.speakerbonnet {
   type hw card 0
}

pcm.dmixer {
   type dmix
   ipc_key 1024
   ipc_perm 0666
   slave {
     pcm "speakerbonnet"
     period_time 0
     period_size 1024
     buffer_size 8192
     rate 44100
     channels 2
   }
}

ctl.dmixer {
    type hw card 0
}

pcm.softvol {
    type softvol
    slave.pcm "dmixer"
    control.name "PCM"
    control.card 0
}

ctl.softvol {
    type hw card 0
}

pcm.!default {
    type             plug
    slave.pcm       "softvol"
}
```

I have tried (unsuccessfully) to follow this guide: https://www.tinkerboy.xyz/raspberry-pi-downmixing-from-stereo-to-mono-sound-output/ which recommends:

```
# convert stereo to mono LEFT output
pcm.monocard{
  slave.pcm "hw:0"
  slave.channels 2
  type route
  ttable {
    # Copy both input channels to output channel 0 (Left).
    0.0 1
    1.0 1
    # Send nothing to output channel 1 (Right).
    0.1 0
    1.1 0
  }
}

pcm.!default monocard
```

I tried all combinations of values for "ttable" as well as trying various values for the "slave" value and other things, but the audio output never seems to change.

I *believe* these are the correct values, but I'm not familiar enough with ALSA configurations and the routing features:

```
ttable {
    # Copy both input channels to output channel 0 (Left).
    0.0 1
    1.0 1
    
    # Copy both input channels to output channel 1 (Right). <= Added by me
    0.1 1
    1.1 1
  }
```

Can anyone assist? Much thanks in advance!